# Accidentally drew polygon in WGS on top of UTM Map in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon, coordinate-system, layers

Is there any way to Change the polygon projections so it remains in place, but takes on the UTM coordinates?

Comment: Note that any reprojection will let the features remain in place, while assigning a different CRS will move them (to the correct place or away from it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "save as".
Right click on the layer on the layer toolbar, save as, chose the location where you will save the file and the CRS.
[image]
Cheers,